# A collection of type `i32` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=_>`

Tags: rust

Today I try to solve a problem on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/day-of-the-year/). This is my code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=750ec92f41d19231f2fcf1e7ef3c330c)):

```rust
#[test]
fn basic_test() {
    assert_eq!(day_of_year("2019-01-09".to_string()), 9);
    assert_eq!(day_of_year("2019-02-10".to_string()), 41);
    assert_eq!(day_of_year("2003-03-01".to_string()), 60);
    assert_eq!(day_of_year("2004-03-01".to_string()), 61);
}

pub fn day_of_year(date: String) -> i32 {
    let vec: Vec<&str> = date.split("-").collect();
    [(vec[0],vec[1],vec[2])].iter().map(|(year,month,day)|
        match month {
            &"01" => day.parse().unwrap(),
            &"02" => day.parse().unwrap() + 31,
            _ => match year.parse().unwrap(){
                y if y%4==0&&y%100!=0 
                    ||y%400==0&&y%3200!=0 
                    ||y%172800==0=>
                        match month {
                            &"03" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+29,
                            &"04" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+29+31,
                            &"05" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+29+31+30,
                            &"06" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+29+31+30+31,
                            &"07" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+29+31+30+31+30,
                            &"08" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+29+31+30+31+30+31,
                            &"09" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+29+31+30+31+30+31+31,
                            &"10" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+29+31+30+31+30+31+31+30,
                            &"11" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+29+31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31,
                            &"12" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+29+31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31+30
                        },
                _ => match month{
                        &"03" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+28,
                        &"04" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+28+31,
                        &"05" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+28+31+30,
                        &"06" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+28+31+30+31,
                        &"07" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+28+31+30+31+30,
                        &"08" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+28+31+30+31+30+31,
                        &"09" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+28+31+30+31+30+31+31,
                        &"10" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+28+31+30+31+30+31+31+30,
                        &"11" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+28+31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31,
                        &"12" => day.parse().unwrap()+31+28+31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31+30
                }
            }
        }
    ).collect()
}
```

I think the code can self-explain. I'm getting this error message:

```
error[E0277]: a collection of type `i32` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `_`
  --> src/lib.rs:45:7
   |
45 |     ).collect()
   |       ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `i32` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=_>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<_>` is not implemented for `i32`
```

I tried changing it to `collect::<Vec<i32>>[0]`. But still getting the compile error. Let me know how can I change the code to make it compile.

Comment: Hi there, a few quick tips on how to ask better questions here on SO. (a) "*I think the code can self-explain."* -> it never hurts to explain it in a few sentences. (b) Add the full code and full error message to your post (as I've done for you now). (c) Tell us *what* you don't understand about the error. (d) Try to simplify your code before posting, search term [MCVE]. In general: show that you care, otherwise you can't expect others to care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over tuple and call `collect` at all. It creates a collection but your goal is just one `i32` value. There is the fixed code: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9d82172d483035ca437fe826c5e9da86)

I also parsed values in advance and added `_` branch in `matche`es because it should be exhaustive. Ideally, you don't need `match` either.

Update: a shorter version of the same code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9a344c64f42332eb26f2a68fa260f72

Answer (score 0):

In the statement `[(vec[0],vec[1],vec[2])].iter()`, you create a (fixed length) array with one element, then immediately iterate over it. The only iterator method you use is `map`, so it would probably be much more idiomatic to simply have

```
let year = vec[0];
let month = vec[1];
let day = vec[2];
```

and then continue from there without using `map`. Better yet, you can use this as an opportunity to parse `day` as an integer, rather than having to parse on every branch of the match statements. This will also fix the issue you have that the type that `day` parses into can't be inferred. You'd have to write `day.parse::<i32>()` every time you parse it, so it's much easier to just to that once at the top. You may as well also parse `year`, since you're going to need to do that below anyway. After these changes, you won't want to parse `day` and `year` again, so remove all the `.parse().unwrap()` statements on them.

```
let year: i32 = vec[0].parse().unwrap();
let month = vec[1];
let day: i32 = vec[2].parse().unwrap();
```

After that, the changes the compiler suggests should be enough to get this to work. You no longer need to match `month` as a `&&str` (e.g. `&"01"`) since you're not creating an array of `&str` and iterating over references into it (in your original code, it would have been better to use `into_iter()` instead of `iter()` to avoid that). Additionally, the compiler will tell you that the match on `month` isn't exhaustive. You'll need to add a catch-all branch in case the input doesn't match any of the other branches. I'd suggest something like `_ => panic!("Invalid month")` at the end of the match statements.

---

Just some extra tips to get your code looking a lot better. The command `cargo fmt` (this tool also exists under "TOOLS" on the playground) will automatically format your code to a more idiomatic style. This just makes it easier to read in general. I'd also recommend running `cargo clippy` (also available on the playground) to catch any possible errors and get your code even more idiomatic. In this case, clippy makes a few small suggestions.

Just a general coding tip, I'd also separate this function into a function that parses the date, and one that finds the number of the day in the year. That way you don't need to do both at once and it's easier to think about. (This doesn't quite fit the format that the challenge gives you, so you'd have to call this parse function from inside the `day_of_year` function).

I understand that the challenge asks you to return `i32`, but since this is a computation that might fail, it would be far better to return an `Option<i32>` (or better yet, a `Result<i32, Error>`, where `Error` is some description of the possible ways this can go wrong). This would work best if you also follow the suggestion above to separate this into two functions. Then you can parse and validate the date in the first function, and then given a valid date, calculate the day of the year. This would let you remove all the `unwrap` calls (and the explicit panic I suggested). Knowing your function won't panic is a nice feeling.

Finally, there's a lot of repetition in this code, so you might be able to factor things out and not repeat yourself so much. For example, instead of having two match statements depending on whether it's a leap year or not, just have a single match and add one if it's a leap year. You might also want to have the number of days in each month in an array like `[31, 28, 31, 30, ...]`. Then you can just use the month number and add up the appropriate number of days.

(also, a very small quibble: the problem specifies that it uses the Gregorian calendar, which doesn't have special cases for leap years at multiples of 3,200 or 172,800)